# Return SQL results to clickable table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a small project. It is a contacts database where users can add and search for contacts. So far you can add contacts and on page load a table populates with results. Great. 
But I want to see if its possible to make each row clickable so that when the row is clicked the data is populated using javascript to the form. 
One idea I am looking at is when the search results are pulled using a select statement, the id field is also selected and put in a hidden th. Then when the link is clicked the form uses a get method to select the data where the id = what has been selected. Would this work? or is there another way?
For brevity I did not use the include file that handles certain errors.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="displayContacts">
<?php

//**********************************************
//*
//*  Connect to MySQL and Database
//*
//**********************************************

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'test');

if (!$db)
{
 print "<h1>Unable to Connect to MySQL</h1>";
}


include "0811_common_functions_mysqli.php";
$outputDisplay = "";
$myrowcount = 0;


//**********************************************
//*
//*  SELECT from table and display Results
//*
//**********************************************
$sql_statement  = "SELECT firstname, lastname, pcat, contact_id ";
//, congroup, cattype, company, position, email, website, phone, mphone, wphone, fax, add1, add2, city, state, zip, country, reference, entrydate, enteredby, notes ";
$sql_statement .= "FROM contacts ";
$sql_statement .= "ORDER BY lastname, firstname";

$sqlResults = selectResults($db, $sql_statement);

$error_or_rows = $sqlResults[0];

if (substr($error_or_rows, 0 , 5) == 'ERROR')
{
 $outputDisplay .= "<br />Error on DB";
 $outputDisplay .= $error_or_rows;
} else {

 $arraySize = $error_or_rows;
 $outputDisplay .= '<table id="resultstable" style="overflow-x:auto;">';
 $outputDisplay .= '<tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th></tr>';
 for ($i=1; $i <= $error_or_rows; $i++)
 {
  $myrowcount++;
  $firstname = $sqlResults[$i]['firstname'];
  $lastname = $sqlResults[$i]['lastname'];
  $pcat     = $sqlResults[$i]['pcat'];
  $contactid = $sqlResults[$i]['contact_id'];
  $outputDisplay .= "<tr>";
  $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$firstname.' '.$lastname."</td>";
   $outputDisplay .="<td>".$contactid."</td>";
  $outputDisplay .= "<tr>";
  $outputDisplay .="<td rowspan=1>&nbsp;$pcat</td>";
 
  
  $outputDisplay .="</tr>";
  $outputDisplay .= "</tr>";
 }

 $outputDisplay .= "</table>";
}

?>
<?php
 $outputDisplay .= "<br /><br /><b>Number of Rows in Results: $myrowcount </b><br /><br />";
 print $outputDisplay;
?>
</div>

 <div id="main" class="main">
    <form action="insert1.php" id="frmBox" method="post" onsubmit="return formSubmit();">
      <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='firstname' class="inp" size='20'  /></th>
    <th>Last Name: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='lastname' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Pages Category: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='pcat' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
    <th>congroup: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='congroup' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Category Type:</th>
    <th> <input type='text' name='cattype' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
    <th>Company: </th>  
    <th><input type='text' name='company' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
    
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Position:</th>
        <th><input type='text' name='position' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
 
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Email:</th>
    <th><input type='text' name='email' class="inp" size='20' /> </th>
    <th>Website: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='website' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>H/D Phone: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='phone' class="inp" size='20'  /></th>
    <th>Mobile Phone: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='mphone' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Work Phone: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='wphone' class="inp" size='20' /> </th>
    <th>Fax: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='fax' class="inp" size='20' /> </th>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Address 1: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='add1' class="inp" size='50' /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Address 2:</th>
    <th><input type='text' name='add2' class="inp" size='50' /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>City: </th>
    <th><input type='text' name='city' class="inp" size='20' /> </th> 
    <th>State:</th>
    <th><input type='text' name='state' class="inp" size='20' /> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Zip/Postal Code:</th>
    <th><input type='text' name='zip' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
    <th>Country:</th>
    <th><input type='text' name='country' class="inp"  size='20' /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Reference:</th>
    <th><input type='text' name='reference' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
    <th>Date Added:</th>
    <th> <input type='text' name='entrydate' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>  
    <th>Entered By: </th>
    <th> <input type='text' name='enteredby' class="inp" size='20' /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Notes:</th>
    <th><textarea name="notes" row="10" class="inp" cols="20"></textarea></th>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th><input type="submit" name="submit" class="sub-btn" value="Submit"></th>
  </tr>
      <h3 id="success"></h3>
</table>

    </form> 
 </div>
<div id="results">
</div>

<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function formSubmit(){
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'insert1.php',
    data:$('#frmBox').serialize(),
    success:function(response){
     $('#success').html(response);
    }
    });
   var form=document.getElementById('frmBox').reset();
   return false;
   }
   
 function addRowHandlers() {
     var table = document.getElementById("resultstable");
     var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
         var currentRow = table.rows[i];
         var createClickHandler = function(row) {
          return function() { 
             var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                var id = cell.innerHTML;
                alert("id:" +id);
    function formPopulate(id){
     $.ajax({
      url: "result.php",
      success: (function(result){
      $("results").html(result);
      })
     })
      
    }
                        };
                };
                currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
                                }
                          }
                window.onload = addRowHandlers();
 </script>
</body>

</html>


Results.php


<!doctype html>
<html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="displayContacts">
<?php

//**********************************************
//*
//*  Connect to MySQL and Database
//*
//**********************************************

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'test');

if (!$db)
{
 print "<h1>Unable to Connect to MySQL</h1>";
}


include "0811_common_functions_mysqli.php";
$outputDisplay = "";
$myrowcount = 0;


//**********************************************
//*
//*  SELECT from table and display Results
//*
//**********************************************
$sql_statement  = "SELECT firstname, lastname, pcat, contact_id ";
//, congroup, cattype, company, position, email, website, phone, mphone, wphone, fax, add1, add2, city, state, zip, country, reference, entrydate, enteredby, notes ";
$sql_statement .= "FROM contacts ";
$sql_statement .= "ORDER BY lastname, firstname";

$sqlResults = selectResults($db, $sql_statement);

$error_or_rows = $sqlResults[0];

if (substr($error_or_rows, 0 , 5) == 'ERROR')
{
 $outputDisplay .= "<br />Error on DB";
 $outputDisplay .= $error_or_rows;
} else {

 $arraySize = $error_or_rows;
 $outputDisplay .= '<table id="result" style="overflow-x:auto;">';
 for ($i=1; $i <= $error_or_rows; $i++)
 {
  $myrowcount++;
  $firstname = test_get($sqlResults[$i]['firstname']);
  $lastname = test_get($sqlResults[$i]['lastname']);
  $pcat     = test_get($sqlResults[$i]['pcat']);
  $contactid = $sqlResults[$i]['contact_id'];
  $outputDisplay .= "<tr>";
  $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$firstname.' '.$lastname."</td>";
   $outputDisplay .="<td>".$contactid."</td>";
  $outputDisplay .= "<tr>";
  $outputDisplay .="<td rowspan=1>&nbsp;$pcat</td>";
 
  
  $outputDisplay .="</tr>";
  $outputDisplay .= "</tr>";
 }

 $outputDisplay .= "</table>";
 mysqli_close($conn);
}
 function test_get($data){
  
 $data=trim($data);
 $data=stripslashes($data);
 $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data; 
 }

?>


</div>
</body>
</html>

insert.php
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username= "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname="test";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if(!$conn){
 die("could not connect:".mysqli_connect_error()); 
} else{


  $firstname=test_input($_POST['firstname']);
  $lastname=test_input($_POST['lastname']);
  $pcat=test_input($_POST['pcat']);
  $congroup=test_input($_POST['congroup']);
  $cattype=test_input($_POST['cattype']);
  $company=test_input($_POST['company']);
  $position=test_input($_POST['position']);
  $email=test_input($_POST['email']);
  $website=test_input($_POST['website']);
  $phone= test_input($_POST['phone']);
  $mphone=test_input($_POST['mphone']);
  $wphone=test_input($_POST['wphone']);
  $fax=test_input($_POST['fax']);
  $add1=test_input($_POST['add1']);
  $add2=test_input($_POST['add2']);
  $city=test_input($_POST['city']);
  $state=test_input($_POST['state']);
  $zip=test_input($_POST['zip']);
  $country=test_input($_POST['country']);
  $reference=test_input($_POST['reference']);
  $entrydate=test_input($_POST['entrydate']);
  $enteredby=test_input($_POST['enteredby']);
  $notes=test_input($_POST['notes']);

  
  
  $sql="INSERT INTO contacts(firstname, lastname, pcat, congroup, cattype, company, position, email, website, phone, mphone, wphone, fax, add1, add2, city, state, zip, country, reference, entrydate, enteredby, notes) ";
 $sql .= "values (";
 $sql .= "'".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$pcat."', '".$congroup."', '".$cattype."', '".$company."', '".$position."', '".$email."', '".$website."', '".$phone."', '".$mphone."', '".$wphone."', '".$fax."', '".$add1."', '".$add2."', '".$city."', '".$state."', '".$zip."', '".$country."', '".$reference."', '".$entrydate."', '".$enteredby."', '".$notes."'";
 $sql .= ")";
  if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
   echo "Record Inserted";
   }else{
    echo "insert failed"; 
   }

 mysqli_close($conn);
}
 function test_input($data){
  
 $data=trim($data);
 $data=stripslashes($data);
 $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data; 
 }


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so when we click on a row you want to show some popup and show some data in it?

Comment: No I want the data to be populated to the  same form where you can add contacts. Although I just noticed that my javascript might be having some problems and isn't posting a response without refreshing the page. But that should not be an issue for my question.

Comment: try ajax call  to get those details

Comment: I have updated my code. I added a function to make the table clickable - when it is clicked an alert is issued echoing the ID. I added a nested function to carry out the tax call and put the select statement in a separate PHP file. Although I haven't added the ID limit to my sql shouldn't the code execute anyway? In other words when I click shouldn't I then see a results output?

Answer (score 0):

For the table tr you call a onclick funtion and send an id through it

```
<tr onClick="formPopulate(id)" >
```

And when the funtion trigger call a ajax call to retrieve the data and the append to form

in javascript

```
 function formPopulate(id) { 
    //send an ajax call here to get the data without reloading the page 
//after ajax call append the values of ajax response to the form
    }
```